# Dúvida ao utilizar xlsx2csv dentro do Python

Tags: python

Estou utilizando o xlsx2csv disponível em: https://github.com/dilshod/xlsx2csv

```
from xlsx2csv import Xlsx2csv
Xlsx2csv("myfile.xlsx", outputencoding="utf-8").convert("myfile.csv")
```

Alguém que já utilizou ou manja de Python, consegue ajudar a entender como faço para utilizar o exemplo acima, mas especificando pelo nome da aba do Excel o conteúdo que quero transformar para CSV?

Exemplo, arquivo xlsx possui as "abas" (planilhas) com nome de "brasil", "eua", "canada".
Quero transformar para CSV apenas a aba do "eua"..

Comment: Olá! Sugiro melhorar o título da sua pergunta, pois não dá para entender sua dúvida com o título que usou. Sua pergunta também poderia ter mais detalhes do seu problema.

Comment: Obrigado, fiz alguns ajustes ;)

Comment: Você pode encontrar a resposta em: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20105118/convert-xlsx-to-csv-correctly-using-python